# Same three heads with three different captions: xltabular

Tags: captions, xltabular

In my thesis, there is a very long table that occupies three pages. According to the ABNT's format (Brazilian things) if a table takes a lot of pages, then the caption must contain the next indication: the first page with `"<name of the bale> to be continued"`, the rest of the pages `"<name of the bale> continuation"` and the last page `"<name of the bale> conclusion"`. I am using the `xltabular` package and I noticed that it is only possible to have two different heads using `\endfirsthead` and `\endhead`, so the `\endhead` caption remains repeated after `\endfirsthead`. I wonder if it is possible to overcome that issue.

The [class](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/pacote-uspsc-modelos-de-trabalhos-de-academicos-em-latex-versao-3-dot-1uspsc-3-dot-1-4/ydqymxwkgcnn) is from Overleaf, which loads memoir. The heads code follows as described here:

```
\documentclass[
% -- memoir class options --
12pt,
openright,
twoside, 
a4paper,            
% -- opções da classe abntex2 --
chapter=TITLE,      % títulos de capítulos convertidos em letras maiúsculas
% -- opções do pacote babel --
english,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
french,             % idioma adicional para hifenização
spanish,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
brazil              % o último idioma é o principal do documento
]{USPSC-classe/USPSC}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{lmodern}    

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}   
\usepackage{multirow}   
\usepackage{longtable}  
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=off, width=0.99\linewidth}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{TableNotes}[flushleft, para]
\footnotesize
Fonte: Elaborado pelo autor.
\end{TableNotes}
{\ABNTEXfontereduzida
\noindent
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\hsize=0.75\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X >{\hsize=1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X >{\hsize=1.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X >{\hsize=.75\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X @{}}
\caption{Lista de microrganismos.}\label{tab-linhagens} \\
        \multicolumn{4}{r}{\raggedleft\arraybackslash (continua)} \\
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Nome}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Gen\'otipo}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Descri\c{c}\~ao}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Fonte}} \\
        \toprule
\endfirsthead
       \caption[]{Lista de microrganismos.}\\  
        \multicolumn{4}{r}{\raggedleft\arraybslash (continua\c{c}\~ao)} \\
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Nome}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Gen\'otipo}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Descri\c{c}\~ao}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Fonte}} \\
        \toprule
\endhead    
        \caption[]{Lista de microrganismos.} \\  
        \multicolumn{4}{r}{\raggedleft\arraybslash (conclus\~ao)} \\
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Nome}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Gen\'otipo}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Descri\c{c}\~ao}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Fonte}} \\
        \toprule
\endhead 
        \insertTableNotes
        \endlastfoot

\blindtext & \blindtext & \blindtext & \blindtext & \\ %the same text until fulfill the third page 

\bottomrule 
\end{xltabular} 

}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Can you please add the missing code, so we can copy and compile your code? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, sure! --> %%% Before the command \noindent.. %%%
\begin{TableNotes}[flushleft, para]
\footnotesize
Fonte: Elaborado pelo autor.
\end{TableNotes}
{\ABNTEXfontereduzida

%%% After the command \endlastfoot.. %%%
\blindtext & \blindtext & \blindtext & \blindtext & \\ %the same text until fulfill the third page

\bottomrule
    \end{xltabular}
}

Comment: Ok, however, the right place is your posted code, and it has to start with \documentclass, and to end with \end{document} ...

Comment: oh, ok sorry, this is the first time in the community. I updated the code above, thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Can you add a link to where we can get the class from?

Comment: No problem Eric, that's why we are here ;-)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Of course, there is a link in Overleaf where the core code source is located: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/pacote-uspsc-modelos-de-trabalhos-de-academicos-em-latex-versao-3-dot-1uspsc-3-dot-1-4/ydqymxwkgcnn -- the class file is inside "USPSC - classes" folder and it is named "USPSC.cls"

Comment: @MS-SPO thank you so much :)

Comment: BTW, if that‘s what your university wants to see … are you the first one with a table spanning 3 pages or more? If not, then there must already be a solution at your university. Can you ask someone in your place?

Comment: Is this a class recommended by your university? A lot of places have a dedicated class designed to meet the university's submission requirements. Sometimes this is official; sometimes unofficial and you have to ask around (e.g. in the maths department).